# How do I swap array elements in an immutable fashion within a Redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, immutability

The relevant Redux state consists of an array of objects representing layers.

*Example:*

```
let state = [
    { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }
]
```

I have a Redux action called moveLayerIndex:

**actions.js**

```
export const moveLayerIndex = (id, destinationIndex) => ({
    type: MOVE_LAYER_INDEX,
    id,
    destinationIndex
})
```

I would like the reducer to handle the action by swapping the position of the elements in the array.

**reducers/layers.js**

```
const layers = (state=[], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'MOVE_LAYER_INDEX':
```

/* What should I put here to make the below test pass */

```
        default:
         return state
    }
}
```

The test verifies that a the Redux reducer swaps an array's elements in immutable fashion.

Deep-freeze is used to check the initial state is not mutated in any way.

**How do I make this test pass?**

**test/reducers/index.js**

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import deepFreeze from'deep-freeze'

const id=1
const destinationIndex=1

 it('move position of layer', () => {
    const action = actions.moveLayerIndex(id, destinationIndex)
    const initialState = [
        {
          id: 1
        },
        {
          id: 2
        },
        {
          id: 3
        }
    ]
    const expectedState = [
        {
          id: 2
        },
        {
          id: 1
        },
        {
          id: 3
        }
    ]
    deepFreeze(initialState)
    expect(layers(initialState, action)).to.eql(expectedState)
 })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the key ideas of immutable updates is that while you should *never* directly modify the original items, **it's okay to make a copy and mutate the copy before returning it**.

With that in mind, this function *should* do what you want:

```
function immutablySwapItems(items, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    // Constant reference - we can still modify the array itself
    const results= items.slice();
    const firstItem = items[firstIndex];
    results[firstIndex] = items[secondIndex];
    results[secondIndex] = firstItem;

    return results;
}
```

I wrote a section for the Redux docs called [Structuring Reducers - Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) which gives examples of some related ways to update data.

Comment: Shouldn't be `items` the array returned?

Comment: Hmm.  No, `tempArray` should be returned, but it should definitely be modifying `tempArray`, not `items`.  I'll fix it.

Comment: My bad! I was looking the wrong function. Yours work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You could use **map** function to make a swap:

```
function immutablySwapItems(items, firstIndex, secondIndex) {
    return items.map(function(element, index) {
        if (index === firstIndex) return items[secondIndex];
        else if (index === secondIndex) return items[firstIndex];
        else return element;
    }
}
```

In ES2015 style:

```
const immutablySwapItems = (items, firstIndex, secondIndex) =>
  items.map(
    (element, index) =>
      index === firstIndex
        ? items[secondIndex]
        : index === secondIndex
        ? items[firstIndex]
        : element
  )
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach... you are traversing the array (complexity O(n)) when you really don' t need to (complexity O(1)).

Comment: Hi @JohnBernardsson, thanks for your comment. You are right when you say that a simple swap is constant whereas returning a new array is linear. However, if check the question, it is about doing it in an Immutable way, which means not change the current array, but rather return a new one. Pretty much all immutable operations in an array will be at least linear... Check this introduction for a brief explanation of the idea of Immutable: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/

Comment: Well, my point was that the example shown in the accepted answer also does it in an immutable way, and without linear complexity. But, it is true that I missed the complexity of the "slice()" operation in the example, which it's going to be O(n) as it copies the full array. So I'll take my words back.. d'oh!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the other two answers, but I think there is even a simpler way to do it with ES6.

```js
const state = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}];

const immutableSwap = (items, firstIndex, secondIndex) => {
  const result = [...items];
  [result[firstIndex], result[secondIndex]] = [result[secondIndex], result[firstIndex]];
  return result;

}

const swapped = immutableSwap(state, 2, 0);

console.log("Swapped:", swapped);
console.log("Original:", state);
```